# Docker, WireGuard, firewalld

Tags: iptables, docker, ubuntu-20.04, wireguard

Environment:

1. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
2. Docker
3. WireGuard
4. firewalld

I checked
`systemctl status firewalld`

I have this message

```
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER' failed: iptables: No cha>
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed>
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed>
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2' failed>
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2' failed>
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptabl>
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptabl>
Mar 10 23:04:29 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-5efaa402a4d3 -o br-5efaa402a>
Mar 10 23:04:30 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: 1;38;5;185mWARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j
 DROP' fai>Mar 10 23:04:31 vpnwaw firewalld[542]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j
```

Answer (score 0):

SystemD won't work reliably in Docker, use [it's replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement).

Download [the file](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement/blob/master/files/docker/systemctl3.py) and copy it to your docker.

```
COPY ./systemctl3.py .
RUN chmod +x *.py && cp -f systemctl3.py /usr/bin/systemctl
```